# Table data row is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, datatable

I'm creating my data table like this

```
function fnBuildTable(response) {

    function Registro(CVPartida, FechaPedido, CantidadSolicitada, Producto, Cliente, Estado, FechaEntrega, EstadoProgramacion, OpHost) {
        this.CVPartida = CVPartida;
        this.FechaPedido = FechaPedido;
        this.CantidadSolicitada = CantidadSolicitada
        this.Producto = Producto;
        this.Cliente = Cliente;
        this.Estado = Estado;
        this.FechaEntrega = FechaEntrega;
        this.EstadoProgramacion = EstadoProgramacion;
        this.OpHost = OpHost;

    }

    var datos = [];
    let FechaEntrega 
    let FechaPedidoCorta
    let Estado

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

        if (response[i].FechaEntrega == "0001-01-01") {
            FechaEntrega = null;
        } else {
            FechaEntrega = response[i].FechaEntrega
        }

        switch (response[i].Estado) {
            case "0":
                Estado = resources.LblActive;
                break;
            case "1":
                Estado = resources.lblInProduction;
                break;
            case "2":
                Estado = resources.lblFulfilled;
                break;
            case "4":
                Estado = resources.lblCancelled;
                break;
            default:
                Estado = "";
                break;
        }

        FechaPedidoCorta = response[i].FechaPedido.substring(0, 10);

        var nuevoRegistro = new Registro(response[i].CVPartida, FechaPedidoCorta, response[i].CantidadSolicitada, response[i].Producto, response[i].Cliente, Estado, FechaEntrega, response[i].EstadoProgramacion, response[i].OpHost);
        datos.push(nuevoRegistro);
    }

    ListaOrdenDeVenta = $('#tblPurchaseOrder').DataTable({


        initComplete: function () {

        },
        //"lengthChange": false,
        //data: response,
        "paging": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        dom: "Bfrtip",
        data: datos,
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: false,
                text: "test",
                title: "test",
                className: 'btn btn-success buttons-excel',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                }
            }
        ],
        //order: [[1, "asc"]],    
        columns: [
            {
                title: tableHeader[0],
                data: null,
                defaultContent: "<div class='dropdown'>" +
                    "<button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>" +
                    "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></i>" +
                    "</button>" +
                    "<ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton'>" +
                    "<li><a class='dropdown-item verQuantity'  >" + resources.lblViewQuantityDetail + "</a></li>" +
                    "<li><a class='dropdown-item verCV' >" + resources.lblViewCV + "</a></li>" +
                    "<li><a class='dropdown-item verPTDA' >" + resources.lblViewItem + "</a></li>" +
                    "</ul>" +
                    "</div>"
            },
            {
                title: tableHeader[1],
                data: 'CVPartida',
                defaultContent: '--',
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                title: tableHeader[2],
                data: 'FechaPedido',
                defaultContent: '--',
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                title: tableHeader[3],
                data: 'CantidadSolicitada',
                defaultContent: '--',
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                title: tableHeader[4],
                data: 'Producto',
                defaultContent: '--',
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                title: tableHeader[5],
                data: 'Cliente',
                defaultContent: '--',
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                title: tableHeader[6],
                data: 'Estado',
                defaultContent: '--',
                className: "text-center estadotxt"
            },
            {
                title: tableHeader[7],
                data: 'FechaEntrega',
                defaultContent: '--',
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                title: tableHeader[8],
                data: 'OpHost',
                defaultContent: '--',
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                title: tableHeader[9],
                data: 'EstadoProgramacion',
                defaultContent: '--',
                className: "text-center"
            },
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                searchable: true,
                // orderable: false,
                'className': 'text-center',
                //"width": "8%", "targets": 0
                'width': 'auto'
            }
        ],
        "language": idioma_espanol,
        "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
            var estado = data.Estado;
            //console.log(estado)
            var color = '';
            if (estado === 'En Produccion' || estado === 'In Production') {
                color = 'rgb(247, 242, 83)'; 
            } else if (estado === 'Cumplida' || estado === 'Fulfilled') {
                color = 'rgb(172, 239, 172)'; 
            } else if (estado === 'Anulada' || estado === 'Cancelled') {
                color = 'rgb(201, 201, 201)'; 
            }

            // Aplica el estilo de fondo a la fila
            $(row).css('background-color', color);
        },
    });
    obtener_data_verCV("#tblPurchaseOrder tbody", ListaOrdenDeVenta, response);
    obtener_data_DetailCV("#tblPurchaseOrder tbody", ListaOrdenDeVenta, response);

}

ar obtener_data_DetailCV = function (tbody, table, response) {
    let valorCIdCV = '';
    let valorDID = '';

    $(tbody).on("click", "a.verQuantity", function () {
        var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();

        for (var item of response) {
            if (item.CVPartida == data.CVPartida) {

                var partes = data.CVPartida.split('/')
                valorCIdCV = partes[0].trim();
                valorDID = partes[1].trim();
            }
        }

        GetQuantityDetail(valorCIdCV, valorDID)
        $('#idMDetailCVPartida').modal('show');
    });
}


var obtener_data_verCV = function (tbody, table, response) {

    let valorCIdCV = '';
    let valorDID = '';

    $(tbody).on("click", "a.verCV", function () {
        var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();

        for (var item of response) {
            if (item.CVPartida == data.CVPartida) {

                var partes = data.CVPartida.split('/')
                valorCIdCV = partes[0].trim();  
                valorDID = partes[1].trim(); 
            }
        }
        GetCVData(valorCIdCV, valorDID)
        $('#PopupOrdenDeVenta').modal('show');
    });

    $(tbody).on("click", "a.verPTDA", function () {
        var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();

        for (var item of response) {
            if (item.CVPartida == data.CVPartida) {

                var partes = data.CVPartida.split('/')
                valorCIdCV = partes[0].trim();
                valorDID = partes[1].trim();
            }
        }
        GetItemData(valorCIdCV, valorDID)
        $('.TabOrdenDeVenta').show();
        $('#PopupOrdenDeVentaPartida').modal('show');
    });
}
```

but when i'm creating my data table for the second time without refreshing the site the value "var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();" is undefined

this is the error i get in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CVPartida')
```

what can i do for not getting an undefined value on my data

i try to made the var data a global variable but didn't work

Comment: Probably not your issue but at a 5 second glance you might use `$(this).closest("tr")` instead of  `$(this).parents("tr")` (my my comment comes without insight into the HTML here...)

Comment: FWIW IF whatever tbody` is in `$(tbody)` you will loose those listeners for that click.  get the event in there `function (event)` and you can check with the `event.delegateTarget` which should be that tbody element

Comment: Is the missing `var` v on `ar obtener_data_DetailCV ` just a paste typo?

Comment: You can store relevant data as attributes on the clicked elements and retrieve it within the event handlers to avoid undefined values. This approach ensures that the data variable is correctly defined when recreating the table.